# How many WordPress instances can i run on Google Compute engine in a single google cloud platform project.

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

i was wondering if anyone knows how many instances of a WordPress site i can potentially run on a n1-standard-4 vm instance on the google compute engine either using compute engine or the container engine with docker. is there a way to run benchmarks to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to get a rough estimate for Google Container Engine would be to run the [WordPress tutorial](https://cloud-dot-devsite.googleplex.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-wordpress) with a minor modification: in the cluster create command, use `--machine-type=n1-standard-4`. Then after following the guide to spin up a replication controller-backed wordpress pod, scale it by running

`kubectl scale rc wordpress --replicas=100`

and see how many replicas get scheduled. Keep in mind that this will just give you a rough estimate of how many instances you can run on an n1-standard-4 gated by cpu/memory. If you actually wanted to run multiple WordPress instances with persistent storage backing, you would follow [this guide](https://cloud-dot-devsite.googleplex.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk/) and repeat n times for as many as you want.